# Installing fiberglass fabric before the second layer of waterproof membrane?

Tags: waterproofing, cement-board

In [this video](https://youtu.be/rsubb1HuLks?t=952) the guy is installing a fiber glass fabric before the second layer of insulation. I think I have seen something similar in the Kerdi videos. Is this something I should use with cement board ?

Comment: I don't see the fiberglass insulation in this video. Do you mean the tapings?

Comment: finer glass fabric this is what he calls it in the video

Comment: It just sealing the drywall joint and make it stronger. I am not sure you need that for cement board though.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea though

Comment: Well, turns out it is not a bad idea. See this video. (Around 7:20) https://www.bing.com/videos/search?q=cemment+board+joint+preparation&view=detail&mid=7A349D24147CDCDC9DD37A349D24147CDCDC9DD3&FORM=VIRE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is a good idea to use on any joints and changes of plane. Each company has their own now including mapei, laticrete, and custom building products etc. but they should be interchangeable for any of the liquid membrane products.

This isn't the same as the kerdiband which is installed with thinset and the product itself is the waterproofing layer

Be careful of buildup in the corners especially if you taped and filled joints in the backer board board with thinset before waterproofing

Comment: I can't find that fiber glass at Home Depot in Canada
I opted Kerdi Band instead https://youtu.be/48pwER0GFSs?t=1112

Comment: Kerdi band is not the same as this fabric and shouldn't be used with a paint on membrane

Comment: I ended up using Kerdi band because I could not find that fiber glass